# Unescape characters of HTML particular tag in String Format java

Tags: java, html, dom

I have below html in String format.

```
 <html>

    <head>
       <title>DEMO</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <tag1 att1="&#38;lt;hello/&#38;gt;" att2="&#38;lt;hi/&#38;gt;" />

        <tag2 attr1="hello" />

    </body>
```

I jusy want to unescape the `att2` attribute value with `<>`, keeping the other values as it is.

Please help.

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: Will the html be formatted differently? Or we can assume that tag1 and att2 will always be in the same line?

Comment: yes attr2 will always occur with tag1. but tag may occur multiple times. with many other tags.

Comment: even if I use doc conversion and than finding the node. how to change the value of the doc. I can get the tag1 node value.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over HTML using Jquery and than apply replace if attribute name of tag is same as you want

```
$(data).find(tagName).each(function(index) {

   var tagValue= $(this).attr("AttributeName");

   // perform your repalce login here unescape(tagValue)

})
```